# weka J48 classifier does not generate any result

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have a data set of about 40000 data points. Each data point has 15 nominal features. 
The data set has 6 classes.
When i load the arff file into weka and try running the J48 classifier, i get no output at all. 
Weka runs for a few seconds and terminates after printing the attribute count and attribute list. 
I get no additional information despite turning the debug flag on. 
What could this mean? and how do i fix it?

Comment: please add some code to your question

Comment: I used the Weka UI, so i do not have any code to share. Checking the "Output Source Code" option does not generate code either

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot/printout of the training and the Parameters of the J48 Classifier could assist if possible.

Comment: I had used a confidence factor of 0.25 and a minNumObj of 2

Answer (score 0):

I increased the java heap size by editing the maxHeap in the RunWeka.ini and that seemed to fix the problem for me. It strange because i'd usually see a visible error for low heap cases.